# Часть строки не влезает в string

Tags: строки, freepascal

Что делать, если не хватает string? Часть строки не пишет 
Freepascal

Comment: Опишите свою проблему в деталях, приведите воспроизводящий пример. Телепаты уже празднуют Новый Год.

Comment: Ну слишком много символов в string, в него влазит только 255, а у меня больше

Comment: Какая версия Паскаля? У современных версий, насколько мне помнится, таких ограничений нету. Или вы используете версию времён MS-DOS?

Comment: Какой именно у вас паскаль? Freepascal?

Comment: Приходится писать на freepascal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Freepascal [большой выбор строковых типов](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types). Вам, возможно, подойдёт `WideString` (`2^32` символов максимально) или `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @АнтонПерехрест: Учтите, что остальные строковые операции там могут требовать других функций.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать))